# Rails way of hiding things that are unpublished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I'm a bit stuck with something that I've previously done countless times in Node or Django.

I'm building an API-only Rails app.

Say I have a `Post` model containing blog posts. The model has a `published` attribute, which determines if a certain post is available already to the larger public.

Obviously, the goal in the controller is to return the JSON of the post(s) if the flag is true.

For collections, I have created a simple scope in my Post model as follows:

```
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
```

However, for single requests I am not sure what is the correct, or rather: the Rails way of handling this. I can "force it out", but I feel like there's a neat "convention over configuration" trick for things like this.

In essence, I'm curious about the cleanest solution for this: **if the post's published attribute is true, return the post object, if it's false, return a 404**

Should I look at scopes? Serializers? Where is the treasure hidden?

Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No golden bullet, but **going with scopes is fine**.

In your controller you probably have something similar to this:

```rb
post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
```

Now, using your `published` scope will work as expected (its kind of/results in an SQL `AND`):

```rb
post = Post.published.find params[:post_id]
```

It will **not** first query all published Posts from the database and then look through them. The beauty of the specific ORM (doing code object <-> database mappings) here is that you will end up with a single query against your database (as can be seen in the log files).

Returning the 404 or whatever is than still up to you/your controllers business - as `find` will raise an exception if nothing is found it defaults to the behavior you wished.